# Rich Text Editor Style Issue in my react project due to use of Chakra UI and it's global scope nature

Tags: css, reactjs, rich-text-editor, chakra-ui

I need a help regarding  Rich Text Editor which I am using in my Chakra based react project. Actually react library which I am using for my project is inheriting the properties defined by ChakraProvider even after I have declared TextEditor Component outside the scope of ChakraProvider.

I tried using the resetScope and disableGlobalScope but the styles are getting disturbed after that.

```
import { Box, ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import "./App.css";
import TextEditor from "./DocsGenerator/TextEditor";
import NavBar from "./NavigationBar/NavBar";
import Hero from "./HeroComponent/Hero";
import FooterContent from "./Footer/FooterContent";

function App() {
  const htmlContent = `<h1 style="text-align:center;">Document</h1>


  
  <p><strong>Note:</strong>hi</p>`;

  return (
    <>
      <ChakraProvider>
        <NavBar />
        <Hero />
        <FooterContent></FooterContent>
      </ChakraProvider>

      <TextEditor generatedContent={htmlContent}></TextEditor>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;


//This is TextEditor comp

import { useState } from "react";
import Jodit from "jodit-react";

interface Props {
  generatedContent: string;
}

const TextEditor = ({ generatedContent }: Props) => {
  const [content, setContent] = useState(generatedContent);
  return (
    <div>
      <Jodit
        className="jodit-component"
        value={content}
        onChange={(value) => setContent(value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default TextEditor;
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.